# docker 1.12 swarm cluster cannot serve static files

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I had a swarm cluster based on **docker 1.12.1** swarm mode.
There are 3 master node and 3 worker node. I have a node.js/express service running upon the cluster.

The service has 5 replicas and public port 8082.
But when i try to access it, it failed if serve static files.

I use `curl` to fetch one static style script from the service as an example.

```
[root@i1-proxy ~]# time curl -v 192.168.100.3:8082/dist/style.css
* About to connect() to 192.168.100.3 port 8082 (#0)
*   Trying 192.168.100.3...
* Connected to 192.168.100.3 (192.168.100.3) port 8082 (#0)
> GET /dist/style.css HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: 192.168.100.3:8082
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
< Last-Modified: Fri, 02 Sep 2016 02:09:20 GMT
< ETag: W/"106e1-156e8a85080"
< Content-Type: text/css; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 67297
< Date: Mon, 05 Sep 2016 02:50:14 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
<
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

real    4m0.657s
user    0m0.019s
sys     0m0.012s
```

It returns the HTTP headers but no HTTP body.

**Add**:

docker info of one master in cluster

```
Containers: 1
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 12
Server Version: 1.12.1
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 59
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge overlay null host
Swarm: active
 NodeID: 99wq9cba397bps7578fxqijq1
 Is Manager: true
 ClusterID: 73oimnw1q8zh9caof3gk6sutw
 Managers: 3
 Nodes: 6
 Orchestration:
  Task History Retention Limit: 5
 Raft:
  Snapshot Interval: 10000
  Heartbeat Tick: 1
  Election Tick: 3
 Dispatcher:
  Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
 CA Configuration:
  Expiry Duration: 3 months
 Node Address: 192.168.100.3
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options: seccomp
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-34-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 7.796 GiB
Name: i-yyk6gta5
ID: VXWN:I4AA:EIY7:4NKF:OQJW:GLIJ:43TJ:L6FO:RQB4:Z4L2:6A7D:EGIP
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
```

And docker version

```
Client:
 Version:      1.12.1
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   23cf638
 Built:        Thu Aug 18 05:33:38 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.1
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   23cf638
 Built:        Thu Aug 18 05:33:38 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Comment: Include all the commands that you use to create your services. Also include `docker info` and `docker version`.

Comment: That's a nodejs issue. Have a look at the log from nodejs.  1) figure out which node has your nodejs container `docker service ps nodejsservice`, 2) then switch your docker client to point to the node `eval $(docker-machine env node-name)`, 3) find out the id of the container running nodejs `docker ps` and then look at its log 4) `docker logs cont-id`.